# GFCI issue with grounded protected receptacle

Tags: gfci

Trying to wire GFCI and a protected receptacle into the same box for 4 outlet set up.    When I wire protected receptacle to LOAD side and connect it to the ground, the GFCI test fails.   If I disconnect ground to protected receptacle, GFCI tests OK but protected receptacle tests “open ground”.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add some photos, or describe how you've wired the devices?

Comment: OP has abandoned this question (see comment below). Mods, close?

Answer (score 1):

The hot line side needs to have the black wire to the brass screw on the line connector side. The white wire from the same cable that the black came from goes to the silver line side.
The load side to your outlets black to brass and white to silver and the bare coppers tied together and attached to the GFCI and outlet ground screws usually green in color.
I believe you have swapped your White neutral from line to load and that will cause the problem you describe.

Comment: The other possibility if it is an old or miswired system. It could be that the ground and neutral aren't properly bonded. If there is a small voltage between the neutral and the ground (whether phantom or leakage) that could cause this same symptom.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The house is mid-century wired with BX.   The outlet is on a NM extension and the NM ground is clamped to BX armor at the junction box where they met so very possible ground is compromised.   Decided to just drop back to just the GFCI outlet since 4 outlet was not necessary and everything tests and works great.